# How does source and channel coding work without cancelling out?

Tags: information-theory, communication

Source coding is basically compressing raw message bits. Channel coding is adding redundancy. Both are counter to one another. Yet, in a digital communication block diagram, they are always next to each other(disregarding A/D convertors and encryptors). How can this process happen without undoing the previous step?

Comment: Hi, Welcome to Cross Validated SE! This question may perhaps be more suited to Theoretical Computer Science SE, but may be good here also. I'm not too well-versed on the specifics of information /coding theory, but after some quick skimming of [coding theory](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coding_theory), I think the key distinction is, and I implore another to provide a concrete example, the types of redundancy/information addressed. Source coding can reduce bits by removing statistical redundancy (lossless compression) or...

Comment: by removing less important/unnecessary information (lossy compression) while Error Control (Channel Coding) adds **useful** redundancy to the data so that the transmission is more robust to disturbances on the transmission channel. A quick example of each from the Wikipedia article is of [ZIP Compression](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZIP_(file_format)) for files being a form of source coding and of the [Reed-Solomon Code](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reed%E2%80%93Solomon_code) for CDs so that dust and scratches impact playback less.

Comment: ...being a form of channel coding. :)